# Sending executable programs into hardware (microprocessor) using RS232 cable

Tags: java, c++, serial-port, hardware, microprocessors

I have a hardware device which can be connected using RS232 cable. Now as per my need i have to transfer java or c++ programs into the microprocessor of the hardware to execute. I have the following questions:

1. how to execute C++/java programs into hardware?
2. how to know that the programs are running?
3. how to get the interface?

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated..
Thank you ....

Comment: it all depends, on the hardware and the OS or controller software, and so on and so forth. try to be a little more *specific*, eh? also, consider reading your system's documentation.

Comment: Ram, could you be more specific please? For example, does the microprocessor have a Java Runtime Environment or not? Does it have an OS, for example, Linux or something else? Without knowing anything about the microprocessor, we can't point you in the right direction.

Comment: @Ewald No it doesn't have JRE and it has TRON os,Hitachi 32 bit microprocessor

Comment: Ah, that's much better. No, I don't know of any JRE that's been ported to TRON/OS at all. You should consult the microprocessor documentation for your particular variant to find out which C or C++ compiler is supported. I've not found any mention of Java for the Tron microprocessor that looks promising.

Comment: @Ewald thank u Ewald for ur response,i want to know if it is possible to execute C++ programs into microprocessor and if yes then how as i have USB and RS232 interface ...

Comment: Hi Ram, you will need the correct drivers set up of your operating system to be able to transfer information to the chip. Do you have the manual? If not, I'd highly recommend you get hold of it, sending data via RS232 or a USB interface can be tricky.

Comment: @Ewald i have no driver set up except USB and RS232.so i have to send entire info. from these interfaces..

Comment: Do you have the instruction manual for the Hitachi chip you are using? That should give some indication as to what is required to program for the chip.

Comment: @Ewald No i dont have that ...

Comment: Then I'd humbly suggest you first obtain that, you might want to start on Google or the Hitachi website. It might be you need special equipment or software to send data to the processor. Before you have the manual, there's not much anyone can tell you.

Comment: If you are just starting programming microcontrollers, if you can, consider to use more common models (for hobbyists), like Atmel AVR or PIC. You will find plenty of information and tools on the web and programmer-hardware can be purchased at low prices. Running a JRE on those controllers might be tricky but c++ (better plain old C) runs natively.

Comment: @Ewald hii .i have got the instruction manual of hitachi chip ..Now plz guide me how and where to start.

Comment: Ok, but for that you need to provide me with a way to see the manual as well. Can you post the link perhaps?  The first step would be to find out what required software you need on your machine. For example, they might say you need an ANSI-C C compiler, or that you need something else specifically, like a special SDK, compiler, assembler etc. needed for the chip. If you provide me with a link to the manual, I can point you at the right chapter to get started.

Comment: @Ewald how to program and test my c++ programs on the processor.Sorry i cant point the link as manual is in pdf format ...Will ANSI-C Compiler will be suitable to compile C++  and the concern is how to run and test the application on the processor ..Any nice link or tool ..

Comment: There are a number of good, free compilers, for example at http://www.thefreecountry.com/compilers/cpp-microcontrollers-pda.shtml  Other than that, if I can't see the manual, there's not much I can help you with. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, executables were converted into absolute positioning binary files then downloaded into RAM via RS232, USB or SDCard.  A simple program on the embedded device can be written to store the data from the RS232 (UART) into memory.

At my work, we are using XModem protocol to load executables into memory.  We have a "bootloader" already programmed into the Flash.  The Bootloader is used to download into RAM then program RAM into the Flash.  On power up, the Bootloader will transfer execution to the Flash, if the Flash content is authenticated.

Another method is to use a JTAG connector.  This will allow you to download a program into RAM that can read the UART and program the Flash.